# perl + ignore lines with remarks and delete duplicate lines with match word

Tags: linux, perl

We create the following Perl one liner. In order to delete double lines except the first match line, the second part of the syntax is to ignore the lines with remark "#".

Example:

```
# more /tmp/test

     # abra_kadabra

abra_kadabra
abra_kadabra


# perl -i -ne -e'next if /^#/; next if /abra_kadabra/ && ++$ok > 1; print' /tmp/test


# more /tmp/test

     # abra_kadabra
```

In fact the Perl syntax is not ignoring the remarked lines in spite we set the `next if /^#/1`:

Please advice what is wrong in my syntax?

Expected output

```
# more /tmp/test

     # abra_kadabra

abra_kadabra
```

Other examples:

```
# more /tmp/test

     # abra_kadabra
#       abra_kadabra
abra_kadabra 1
abra_kadabra 2
abra_kadabra 3
abra_kadabra 4
```

Expected output:

```
# more /tmp/test

     # abra_kadabra
#       abra_kadabra
abra_kadabra 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next if /^#/; ...; print` means the lines that start with `#` will not be printed.

Here, you want

```
perl -i -ne 'next if !/^\s*#/ && /abra_kadabra/ && $count++; print' /tmp/test
```

That is you want *not* to call `next` for the commented-out lines if you want to preserve them.

Same with `sed` for  those implementations that support `-i` (`-i ''` with FreeBSD and derivatives):

```
sed -i -e '/^[[:space:]]*#/b' -e '/abra_kadabra/!b' -e 'x;/./d;g' /tmp/test
```

Where we use the *hold space* to remember if we've already seen `abra_kadabra` before.

Comment: yes I test it and seems its work ( +1 )

Answer (score 0):

You have anchored the `#` to match only at the beginning of a line.  If you want to skip all lines that begin with '#', even after leading whitespace, you need:

```
next if /^\s*#/
```

This will skip lines with optional, leading whitespace followed by a `#`.

Comment: I see another problem that all lines with mark are deleted also , can we fix that? see please example of expected output